# How do I alter column to support unicode

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have created a simple database table called `players`:

```
CREATE TABLE player (
    id              int(10)
                    NOT NULL
                    AUTO_INCREMENT
                    PRIMARY KEY,

    name            varchar(256)
                    NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE  players
    CHANGE name name
        varchar(256)
        CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
        COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I want to insert this entry into the database `''` so I type

```
INSERT INTO player (name) VALUES ("")
```

However, when inserted, the name value becomes `'???????????'`.

How can I fix this and keep my database table as efficient as possible.?

Most of the names are normal ASCII characters but sometimes I have these fancy unicode characters.

Comment: This works as expected in [this MySQL 5.7 db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tiGGAWcSFNa5GwokyaL3wj/0).

Comment: Also it could be that values are properly inserted by your client does not display them properly.

Comment: @GMB What do you mean not displayed properly? I am viewing it on phpmyadmin

Comment: Are you inserting with phpmyadmin too? Also, please check the db fiddle I linked, you can see that the data is properly inserted and viewed.

Comment: @GMB I saw that link and yea, it inserts properly. I am inserting using PHP

Comment: Can you try inserting with phpmyadmin and see if you have the same issue or not?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode.html

Comment: @GMB You are right. Its a fault in my PHP code. it works fine when I insert through phpmyadmin

Comment: OK. Please try adding this command to your PHP code before you run the insert: `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed over the comments : you have correctly altered your table so the `name` column accepts utf8 characters.

In **[this MySQL 5.7 DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tiGGAWcSFNa5GwokyaL3wj/0)**, string `''` is properly inserted and displayed.

It is very likely that the issue that you are having commes from your client, which is not properly passing data to the MySQL server.

Since you are using PHP with the mysqli extension, you can set the default client character set for the connection by using [the `mysqli::set_charset` function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php):

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8mb4");
```

Comment: Testing this out.

Comment: Thank you. I just changed the character set to utf8mb4 and it worked